# Add "TBD" if value is empty KO

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following KO property:

```
self.property= ko.observableArray([]);
```

And the HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: pvm.property, visible: pvm.property().length">
    <p data-bind="text: address"></p>
</div>
```

How do I display a "TBD" value if `pvm.property` is empty?

Comment: Add a sibling `<div>` with `visible: pvm.property().length === 0`

Comment: I was looking for a more elegant solution because I have 4 divs that I need to add this on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't really explained what you mean by "elegant solution". One way might be to not hide the element using `visible`, but to make a css class that does custom styling and uses an `::after` pseudo element for the empty state content.

```js
var i = 0;
var items = ko.observableArray([]);
var add = function() {
  items.push(++i);
};

ko.applyBindings({
  items: items,
  add: add
});
```

```css
.is-empty::after {
  content: "TBD";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: items, css: {'is-empty': !items().length }">
    <p data-bind="text: $data"></p>
</div>

<button data-bind="click: add">add item</button>
```

You could even define the placeholder text in the element and keep it dynamic in the css:

```
.is-empty::after {
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
}
```

In html:

```
<div data-placeholder="TBD" ... ></div>
```

or

```
<div data-bind="attr: { 'data-placeholder': 'TBD' }"></div>
```

```js
var i = 0;
var items = ko.observableArray([]);
var add = function() {
  items.push(++i);
};

ko.applyBindings({
  items: items,
  add: add
});
```

```css
.is-empty::after {
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: items, 
                css: {'is-empty': !items().length },
                attr: {'data-placeholder': 'TBD' }">
    <p data-bind="text: $data"></p>
</div>

<div data-placeholder="TBD" data-bind="foreach: items, 
                css: {'is-empty': !items().length }">
    <p data-bind="text: $data"></p>
</div>



<button data-bind="click: add">add item</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the first option works nicely, but I would want to avoid putting text ("TBD") in ccs, but I can't get the second option to work. Would you be able to help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: I included another code snippet that shows the second option

Comment: Working perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can show the element when the `property` array has length, which means you can do the same for another element when the `property` array does *not* have a length.

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: pvm.property, visible: pvm.property().length">
    <p data-bind="text: address"></p>
</div>
<div data-bind="visible: !pvm.property().length">TBD</div>
```

To improve user experience you can hide one of them (or both) with CSS until the binding has actually run. This would prevent elements jumping around in the split-second between page load and viewmodel load.

Answer (score 0):

how about another observable that just has the TBD.  then data bind like `data-bind='foreach: courses().length > 0 ? courses : emptyCourses'`

here is a fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/othkss9s/22/